# How to get actual path from string in c#

Tags: c#, string

Hi am facing issue to pass path in File.Copy() method. 
Here I have created a string dest. While I am passing it in File.copy(), it is taking "\" double slash. Because of this, I am getting error of illegal character. Please look into it.

```
string dest = (@"\" + Environment.MachineName +@"\"+ Path.Replace(@"\\",@"\")).Replace(":", "$");  //the value get -"pt-LTP-109\\C$\\Temp\\192.168.0.205\\fileFolder"
dest = dest.Replace("\\\\", @"\") +"\\"+ "filename.txt"; // the value get -"\\pt-LTP-109\\C$\\Temp\\192.168.0.205\\fileFolder\\filename.txt"                             
dest = ("\"").ToString()+dest+"\""; //the value get- "\"\\pt-LTP-109\\C$\\Temp\\192.168.0.205\\fileFolder\\filename.txt\""
    File.Copy(source, dest, true);`
```

Comment: Why are you adding quotes into the path? That will definitely make it invalid. And how do you check the strings? If in a debugger it will double the backslashes due to escaping. Also if this is supposed to be an UNC path you need double backslash in the beginning which you don't have. I assume your issue is only adding quotes and not having a double backslash, nothing with removing backslashes.

Comment: For starters paths shouldn't contain quotes (`"`). You have a really strange way of constructing your paths... What are you actually trying to accomplish with all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very complicated way of doing something so simple... To convert a normal path into a UNC path you only need to do two things:

1. Replace `:` with `$` (which you are doing correctly).
2. Prepend the path with two backslashes and the machine name.

Your code can be shortened to this:

```
string dest = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName, Path.Replace(":", "$"), "filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Path.GetFullPath(dest).Replace(@"\",@"\\");
```

Comment: I hardly think he wants to duplicate _every_ backslash. Doing so will also make the path invalid.

Comment: @Code_Beginner I believe it would be bad practice to use this answer...

Comment: @VisualVincent and Alex M. Do you have any idea why this worked? I don't think you do, if you voted down this answer, you just don't understand it and that's why you think it's wrong

Comment: Do you know yourself why it worked? I haven't ran this through a debugger yet, but a path shouldn't include double backslashes (except for the beginning of a UNC path). Thus forcing it to have so is just bad practice, even if it works (for now).

Comment: A good way to avoid downvotes, by the way, is to include an explanation with the answer so that other readers (and the OP) can get a hunch of what went wrong and why your solution fixes it.

Comment: This is the output that I get from running your code using each of the OP's three modifications above: `C:\\COMPUTERNAME\\C$\\Temp\\192.168.0.205\\fileFolder` and `C:\\COMPUTERNAME\\C$\\Temp\\192.168.0.205\\fileFolder\\filename.txt` and the third one just throws an exception, because of the quotes he/she puts in the path. Neither of those two look like paths that the OP would actually have on his/her computer (or anyone else for that matter). And even if that is the case, it should still not include double backslashes (even if it works for now).